# circle class with methods

Tags: java, class, methods

I am creating a circle class program that checks whether circles have overlapped each other. There are six initial given methods: `getter methods for x,y, and radius and setter methods for x,y, and radius`(6). There are two additional given methods: `getArea method` (returns the area's value) and `doesOverLap method` (returns which circles overlap or do not overlap). There are many demos within this source folder, but the following is the bulk (excuse indentation):

```
public class MyCircle 
{


    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double radius;

    private double other_x; //keeps user input for other_x
    private double other_y; //keeps user input for other_y
    private double other_radius;    //keeps user input for other_radius

    private double third_x; //keeps user input for third_x
    private double third_y; //keeps user input for third_y
    private double third_radius;    //keeps user input for third_radius


    /*
    The setX method stores a value in the x field. 
    @ param value The value to store in x.
    */
    public void setX(double value)
    {
        x = value;
    }

    /*
    The setY method stores a value in the y field.
    @ param value The value to store in y.
    */
    public void setY(double value)
    {
        y = value;
    }

    /*
    The setRadius method stores a value in the radius field.
    @param value The value to store in radius.
    */
    public void setRadius(double value) 
    {
        radius = value;
    }

        /*
        The getX method returns x's value. 
        @return The value in the x field.
        */
        public double getX()
        {
            return x; //returns value input for x
        }

        /*
        The getY method return y's value.
        @return The value in the y field.
        */
        public double getY()
        {
            return y; //returns value input for y
        }

        /*
        The getRadius method returns radius's value.
        @return The value in the radius field.
        */
        public double getRadius()
        {
            return radius; //returns value input for radius
        }

        /*
        The getArea method returns the circle object's area.
        @return The product of 3.14159 * radius * radius (area = 3.14159(pie) * radius * radius).
        */
        public double getArea()
        {       
            return radius * radius * 3.14159;
        }

        public boolean doesOverlap(MyCircleTest OtherCircleTest) 
        {
            double distance;

            distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(other_x - x, 2) + Math.pow(other_y - y, 2));
            return distance < other_radius + radius;


            if(distance < other_radius + radius)
            {
                System.out.println("My other circle overlaps my circle");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("My other circle does not overlap my circle");
            }
        }



            /*
            The setOtherX method stores a value in the x field. 
            @ param value The value to store in x.
            */
            public void setOtherX(double value)
            {
                other_x = value;
            }

            /*
            The setOtherY method stores a value in the y field.
            @ param value The value to store in y.
            */
            public void setOtherY(double value)
            {
                other_y = value;
            }

            /*
            The setOtherRadius method stores a value in the radius field.
            @param value The value to store in radius.
            */
            public void setOtherRadius(double value) 
            {
                other_radius = value;
            }

            /*
            The getOtherX method returns x's value. 
            @return The value in the x field.
            */
            public double getOtherX()
            {
                return other_x; //returns value input for x
            }

            /*
            The getY method return y's value.
            @return The value in the y field.
            */
            public double getOtherY()
            {
                return other_y; //returns value input for y
            }

            /*
            The getRadius method returns radius's value.
            @return The value in the radius field.
            */
            public double getOtherRadius()
            {
                return other_radius; //returns value input for radius
            }

            /*
            The getArea method returns the circle object's area.
            @return The product of 3.14159 * radius * radius (area = 3.14159(pie) * radius * radius).
            */
            public double getOtherArea()
            {       
                return other_radius * other_radius * 3.14159;
            }

            public boolean doesOverlap(MyCircleTest OtherCircleTest) 
            {

                //Equation to see whether circles overlap

                double distance_2;

                distance_2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(other_x - third_x, 2) + Math.pow(other_y - third_y, 2));
                return distance < other_radius + third_radius;


                if(distance_2 < other_radius + third_radius)
                {
                    System.out.println("My other circle overlaps my third circle");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("My other circle does not overlap third circle");
                }

            }

                public void setThirdX(double value)
                {
                    third_x = value;
                }

                /*
                The setThirdY method stores a value in the third y field.
                @ param value The value to store in third y.
                */

                public void setThirdY(double value)
                {
                    third_y = value;
                }

                /*
                The setThirdRadius method stores a value in the third radius field.
                @param value The value to store in third radius.
                */

                public void setThirdRadius(double value) 
                {
                    third_radius = value;
                }

                    /*
                    The getThirdX method returns third x's value. 
                    @return The value in the third x field.
                    */
                    public double getThirdX()
                    {
                        return third_x; //returns value input for third x
                    }

                    /*
                    The getY method return third y's value.
                    @return The value in the third y field.
                    */

                    public double getThirdY()
                    {
                        return third_y; //returns value input for third y
                    }

                    /*
                    The getThirdRadius method returns third radius's value.
                    @return The value in the third radius field.
                    */

                    public double getThirdRadius()
                    {
                        return third_radius; //returns value input for third radius
                    }

                    /*
                    The getArea method returns the circle object's area.
                    @return The product of 3.14159 * radius * radius (area = 3.14159(pie) * radius * radius).
                    */
                    public double getThirdArea()
                    {       
                        return third_radius * third_radius * 3.14159;
                    }


                    public boolean doesOverlap (MyCircleTest ThirdCircleTest) 
                    {

                        //Equation to see whether circles overlap

                        double distance_3;

                        distance_3 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(third_x - x, 2) + Math.pow(third_y - y, 2));
                        return distance_3 < third_radius + radius;


                        if(distance_3 < third_radius + radius)
                        {
                            System.out.println("My third circle overlaps circle");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("My third circle does not overlap circle");
                        }

                    }
}
```

I am having trouble on the final method, doesOverLap method, which should state the overall results of the program. It should state whether or not two circles overlap. Also, I am supposed to display the area values of each circle, which isn't in my code.

Requirements are the following:
There are three circle objects, two of them should overlap and two of them should not. The areas of the three circles are to be displayed. The doesOverLap method should indicate which circles over lap and which do not. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Hinted Given: two circles overlap if the sum of their radius' is greater than the distance between their centers.

Comment: Your code is not object oriented at all. Your three circles should be objects of the same class - in your code, the circle class stores the position of all circles. Furthermore, you have several doesOverlap methods, which should not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as @JF Meier pointed out in the comments, this is not the OO approach. You should have a class `Circle` which contains data and logic relevant for only a single circle and then create multiple instances of the `Circle` class with which you can work.
Also, I don't know if this code template was provided or created by yourself, but the initial data should be passed through a **constructor** rather than having only setters. Which makes sense, because a circle should be immutable in my opinion.

For example:

```
public class Circle {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;
    private final double radius;

    public Circle(double x, double y, double radius) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

With this, you need only one variant of `getArea()` and `doesOverlap(Circle other)` because now each of those methods "belong" to one Circle object alone.

Now you can simply create new instances of multiple circles and use your methods on them.

BTW: If you have parameters in one of your methods like `doesOverlap(Circle other)` make sure you actually **use** `other` inside.